# Can ∞-category be defined in proof assistants?

Tags: type-theory, proof-assistants

Can ∞-category be defined in proof assistants?

For example, we can directly consider a function such as `morph 0 : Type, morph 1 : morph 0 -> morph 0 -> Type, morph 2 : (x y : morph 0) -> morph 1 x y -> morph 1 x y -> Type, ...`. Do you think it is possible to define a class of ∞-categories as a dependent sum for such the function?

Comment: Most likely a duplicate: https://mathoverflow.net/q/304263/41291 https://mathoverflow.net/q/145770/41291 https://mathoverflow.net/q/137135/41291

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე They may be answers to my question. However, I am not limiting foundations to homotopy type theory.

Comment: Have you tried [Globular](http://globular.science/)? Its [description](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.01093.pdf) includes links to some other related stuff, like [Orchard](https://github.com/ericfinster/orchard) or [Quantomatic](https://quantomatic.github.io/)

Comment: Which definition of $\infty$-category to do you want? [Maltsiniotis' version](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck-Maltsiniotis+infinity-category)? The [opetopic version](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/opetopic+omega-category)? [Batanin's version](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Batanin+omega-category)? [Trimble's version](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Trimble+n-category)? [Semistrict](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semi-strict+infinity-category)? [Strict](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+omega-category)? [complicial sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weak+complicial+set)?

Comment: what you are writing here is not an $\infty$-category, it is a globular set.

Comment: The answer is of course yes once you choose a particular definition of $\infty$-category in ordinary mathematics, since proof assistants are capable of encoding ordinary mathematics. Maybe you're really interested in a more specific question though.

Comment: @ReidBarton You're right. I am setting up an unspoken context, and I can't put it into words very well. I'll come back with another question when I have more knowledge.

Comment: For those interested in Proof Assistants, there is a new proposed SE site [ProofAssistants](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants?referrer=Njg4YTJmMjYwOTIxNjdkNGEyMmZkNzE0Y2M4YmFhOTY3OWVmNDUwNWM3ZmFlMjYwYTRiYzZiZWY1ODg5ZjdiMqfBIyhShuHO9QbGuJfVwOYRvfVgPfbJQrn2UOFTeOe-0)